# How to check all columns within my for loop

Tags: javascript

The teaching assistant said that by using "return" I am only checking one column out of the four, when I need to check all four. How would I do this?

This is my code so far...

```javascript
function colCheck(arr) {
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
        if(singleColCheck(arr,i) == true){
            return true; 
        }
        else{
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

It needs to return a boolean value of false, which it already does, but i need to make sure that it checks all four columns

Comment: you want `true` and `false` for all columns?

Comment: Simplify to `return singleColCheck(arr,i);` as it already returns a boolean value.

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to return true when they are all true, then if you find one that is false you can return false. Otherwise return true at the end of the function.

```
function colCheck(arr) {
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if (!singleColCheck(arr, i)) return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

You could also use `Array.prototype.every` or `Array.prototype.indexOf` instead of doing that loop check.

```
function colCheck(arr) {
    return arr.every(function (val, i) { return singleColCheck(arr, i); });
}

function colCheck(arr) {
    return arr.indexOf(function (val, i) { return !singleColCheck(arr, i); }) === -1;
}
```